# How to use neo4j as input to hadoop?

Tags: hadoop, neo4j

I have a large neo4j database. I need to check for multiple patterns existing across the graph, which I was thinking would be easily done in hadoop. However, I'm not sure of the best way to feed tuples from neo4j into hadoop. Any suggestions?

Comment: What is "large" ? What kinds of patterns are you looking for?

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion, while it can be done, I don't think MapReduce (which I believe is what you mean when you say "Hadoop") is a good (or at least performant) choice for graph analytics. You want a [Bulk Synchronous Parallel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bulk_synchronous_parallel) approach instead. If you want to perform cloud-scale graph analytics, you want [Apache Giraph](http://giraph.apache.org/), which "understands" the Hadoop ecosystem.

Then again, I would ask why you need to use anything outside of Neo4J at all. I don't know your use case obviously, but first make sure you can't do what you need to do within Neo4J.

Comment: I have a requirement to push my property graph model to a distributed system like Hadoop as there is an issue of scalability when the number of nodes goes high. Is there any way to bypass neo4j and directly push the data to Hadoop and process it? I have read about Graphx and Gradoop but am not sure how to proceed. Any documents or references would be appreciated.